# How Do We Add Python Library(google_meter.py) in IronPython?

Tags: .net, python, ironpython

Hi i am going to code for retrieving google data i am using Iron Python then can you please let me know how do we add google_meter.py file in iron python and access its methods as i am new to python?

Thanks in Advance,
-Mohsin

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read the part of the Python manual that explains [how modules work](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).